# PHP - Using $_POST to update session array

Tags: php, session, post

I'm new to using PHP sessions and I'm having trouble updating a session array using the form $_POST method.

Basically, each button has a value that I want to add to the array `$_SESSION['items']` on each click. However, currently what is happening is the array gets reset and replaced by the last selected value.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
<?
session_name("test");
session_start();
?>


<form method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="item[]" value="Item 1">Item 1</button>
    <button type="submit" name="item[]" value="Item 2">Item 2</button>
</form>


<?
$_SESSION['items'] = array();
array_push($_SESSION['items'], $_POST['item']);
print_r($_SESSION['items']);
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Definitely remove this line :) `$_SESSION['items'] = array();` because it resets your session array each time. Or better do like this `if(!isset($_SESSION['items'])) $_SESSION['items'] = array();` to initialize it only one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're resetting the Session array with

```
$_SESSION['items'] = array();
```

Leaving that bit out seems to do the trick.

I also suggest you change the name of the buttons to just "item", as you otherwise add an array to your session array with each click and not just a single value. Unless of course that's exactly what you intended.

The new script would look like this:

```
<?
session_name("test");
session_start();
?>


<form method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="item" value="Item 1">Item 1</button>
    <button type="submit" name="item" value="Item 2">Item 2</button>
</form>


<?
array_push($_SESSION['items'], $_POST['item']);
print_r($_SESSION['items']);
?>
```

Comment: That worked great, thanks. Can't believe I overlooked something so simple!!

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION['items'] = array();` this line is resetting the $_SESSION['items'] every time the page is loaded. If you want to initialize the array, try,

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['items']) ) {
    $_SESSION['items'] = array();
}
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could try something like:

```
$_SESSION['items'] = $_POST['items'];
```

If you wanted to add an array instead of a value to the session you can try something like this:

```
$items= new array(
    "1" => "item1",
    "2" => "item2");
$_SESSION['items'] = $items;
```

Answer (score 0):

$_SESSION is already an array, no need to declare it. At the top of the script you have already created `$_SESSION['test']`

Try

```
<?
array_push($_SESSION['test'], $_POST['item']);
print_r($_SESSION['test']['item']);
?>
```

You may also need to reverse these for it to work.

```
session_start();
session_name("test");
```